# How to return a ReadLine() function in C?

Tags: c, string, function, readline

I'm a little stuck here... When using this `conReadLine()` function twice, it returns the same address as the second string I read in earlier. For example, if it asks for a name twice, and I enter "NameA" and "NameB", the stored results are "NameB" and "NameB". I understand why this is happening, but I can't figure out how to solve it. Declaring 'buffer' as static is going to do the same thing. How can I get this function to return a separate address on each string?

```
const char *conReadLine(void)
{   
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];

    fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stdin);

    // Check for newline character.
    char *newline = strchr(buffer, '\n');
    if (newline)
        *newline = '\0';  

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: To highlight code on SO, indent _all_ lines by 4 spaces. (Also, tabs? Ew.)

Comment: Code Monkey, yes. If you want more you'll have to pay for it. I'm thinking about allocating buffer with it's own memory and return it. But that might make some interesting bugs too.

Comment: Why does this have the C++ tag?  The C++ way of doing it would be very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this:

```
const char *conReadLine(void)
{   
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
    // something
    return buffer;
}
```

Is returning a pointer to deallocated stack which is very bad. it also brings unpredictable results which includes reusing the same address with other invocations and even other function all together!

you need to do this instead:

```
const char *conReadLine(void)
{   
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUFFER);
    // something
    return buffer;
}
```

which will get you a fresh memory location every time. just remember to `free` it when you are done with it.

Comment: In C some consider it bad practice to cast the return value of `malloc` but +1 for being the first one to say "returning stack memory is bad."

Comment: @Chris Lutz: why they consider it a bad practice? just because it is not required?

Comment: If you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`, `malloc` is implicitly declared (when you first use it) as `int malloc(size_t)`, which is a problem on platforms where `sizeof(int) < sizeof(void *)` - the pointer values will get silently truncated, potentially ruining all your pointers returned by `malloc`. Also, if the type of `buffer` changes (say, to `wchar_t`), you'll have to change the cast as well. This can get tedious to do, especially if you use `malloc` and `realloc` a lot. `char *buffer = malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof *buffer)` will work no matter what type `buffer` is changed to.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: malloc is implicitly defined? it should come from libc which is platform and even configuration specific, which the compiler shouldn't be aware of. the call to `int malloc(size_t)` is different from the call to `void *malloc(size_t)` stack wise, so they just can't fit together on x64 platforms.

Comment: No, it's not implicitly _defined_. If you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`, then under the C89 rules when you first use `malloc` it will be implicitly declared as returning an `int`. The calls are no different, just the return values, which is why if it is implicitly declared (on accident) the generated assembly will be wrong. Fortunately GCC warns when standard library functions are implicitly declared, but not all compilers do.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: there is still problem where the returned type is bigger than the value you take. a `long` will be pushed on stack, while only a `int` will be poped which will result in stack corruption and segfault sooner or later.

Comment: That's my point. If you forget (on accident) `#include <stdlib.h>` it can cause serious errors, and using the cast can silence what would be a compile-time error so that you only see a segfault.

Answer (score -1):

It is a classic!

The function returns a pointer to an inner variable (the buffer). So, basically, your data is in part of the memory (the stack) where successive call to other functions will overwrite it.

In this case, as you call the same function twice, the position of the variables is exactly the same. So, the memory where `nameA` is written, is overwritten with `nameB` and the following call.

more fun: create a function

```
const char *intermediate(void) {
  char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
  return conReadLine();
}
```

the first time call conReadLine and the second one intermediate. The extra function call and the local variable will have "desplaced" the memory location so it will no longer overwrite it!

Two solutions:

1) instead of storing the data in a static defined buffer, get some memory from the heap using `malloc` (remember to `free`it when it no longer is necessary).

2) after the first call, copy the contents of the buffer in another location so you can have them disponible when you need it.

Welcome to the world of C pointers!

Comment: 2 is not really acceptable. It's _never_ correct to return a pointer to automatic memory. The correct way is to pass a buffer (in automatic storage) and its length as a parameter, and in the function copy the data into that.

Comment: Well yes. Option #1 is strongly advised in production. Yet check solution #2 if you want to see how it works.

Comment: I can see how it "works" and it doesn't. It's just as undefined behavior as the OP's solution and the fact that it _does_ work for you is a fluke. There is no good reason to ever use that when a much more well-defined (and much less expensive in terms of the amount of data that gets copied) option exists.

Comment: It's one of the reasons C is fun if you like to twiddle with blinkenlights and knobs. You have to really THINK what you're doing or else it WILL end up in a mess. No slacking allowed when coding C.

Comment: Learning is good. Learning the right way is better. Why teach the wrong way when you can teach the right way?

Comment: @Chris Lutz I already agreed that he should use #1. But if I just say "use malloc" the poster will have a function that works but won't understand how the stack works or why its original code didn't work. Saying "use malloc; see what happens when you do this or that" the poster gets both of it.

Comment: @SJuan76 - My point was that there is a solution that a) doesn't _need_ `malloc` and b) is safe. I'd use `malloc` too, but if the OP was worried about lots of heap allocations, I'd like him to know that there's a safe alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I did this for now: conReadLine(strName, 80); Basically it is fgetc(...) in a way. I just don't want 100 lines of free(myallocarray) at the end of main(void). Although it's the correct thing to do, it's still repetitive.

Comment: @Phil - That's not really what this (or any answer) recommended but it is the correct way to do it without `malloc`.

Comment: A function called freeAll() would be nice with these answers... somehow appending the address each time conReadLine() is called with allocation. Then use a for loop calling free() on each address. My application would be on for 1-5 hours at a time. Or none at all, if they hate it.

Comment: @Phil C does not control if you use or not the memory mallocated, so you must free it manually. Yet you should use it when you no longer need it (v.g. at the end of the main loop). Calling free() before exiting the program is correct but it does nothing (all the memory will be recalled by the OS even if you do not free it).

Comment: Java's not fit for my application needs. And I'm not looking for automatic memory management. I'm looking for an easy way to manage this list of addresses, and I think an array may even work because my application won't be requiring more than 100 addresses of input. So linked lists aren't really needed, I think. What I'm doing is making an allocated version and pass by array.

Comment: This may do it..  str_mgr[str_mgr_index++] = buffer;

Comment: For the record, you "can" imitate automatic memory management at the end of a program with atexit(freeAllocatedResources); called from your initialization functions. Remember C built Java... you can be as creative as you want to in C, even the corny ways will get the job done at the end of the day. Ciao!